# How to make a query monthly in the context of the last 12 months in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please advise on the issue:

I have a SQL query that generates a result (Report "Employee Average First Response Time") .

The report currently collects statistics for the current month only.

How can I modify the query so that it returns the result for the last 12 months?

(i.e. the result of the time for April 2023, March 2023, February 2023, January 2023, December 2022, etc.)

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
with My_request as

(select jiraissue.pkey , min(age(jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created))as first_time_response
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%TPAGENT-%'
and (jiraissue.created between (date_trunc('month', now())::date ) and now()::date)
group by jiraissue.pkey
order by first_time_response asc)

select avg(sum_first_t_r) as avg_time_response, now() as date_column 
from (select pkey, (sum(first_time_response)) as sum_first_t_r from My_request group by pkey) as table_avg_time_response
```

Current result DB:

| avg_time_response | date_column |
| --- | --- |
| 00:51:41.634325 | 2023-04-25 14:47:19 |

and another columns :

| pkey | first_time_response |
| --- | --- |
| JIRAISSUE-133328 | 00:00:47.984 |

| jiraaction.created | jiraissue.created |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-25 13:17:42 | 2023-04-25 13:00:42 |

(jiraaction.created) - date the comment was created

(jiraissue.created) - date the issue was created

Comment: Change the WHERE condition and use something like NOW() - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' to go back one year

Comment: @FrankHeikens GREETINGS! THE THING IS THAT I NEED TO RECEIVE THE RESULTS TOTALLY FOR THE YEAR, BUT SEPARATELY FOR EACH MONTH.

Comment: @FrankHeikens The fact is that this is my first such serious request in pg and I'm stuck at this point. I do not understand how to change the request further

Comment: Hi. Could you provide some test data along with your current query? It would be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: @Albina hello! Fine. I have updated the information in the description of my question. If you need any more information, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @Albina , is there enough data? Or do you need to add something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
try this:

```
with base as (
select ji.pkey, ji.created as issue_created_at, min(ja.created) as action_created_at
from jiraissue ji
inner join jiraaction ja on ja.issueid = ji.id 
where ji.pkey like '%TPAGENT-%'
and date_trunc('month', ji.created) = date_trunc('month', now())  
group by ji.pkey, ji.created
)
select to_char(now(), 'month YYYY') as current_month, avg(age(action_created_at, issue_created_at)) as avg_first_response
from base
```

It select only issue created on the current month and the first response from jiraaction table. And you calculate the difference between the issue creation date and the first action response and do the average.

If you want the average per month for the last 12 month you could do something like that:

```
with base as (
select ji.pkey, ji.created as issue_created_at, min(ja.created) as action_created_at
from jiraissue ji
inner join jiraaction ja on ja.issueid = ji.id 
where ji.pkey like '%TPAGENT-%'
and date_trunc('month', ji.created) between date_trunc('month', now() - interval '12 month') and date_trunc('month', now())  
group by ji.pkey, ji.created
)
select to_char(issue_created_at, 'month YYYY') as "month", avg(age(action_created_at, issue_created_at)) as avg_first_response
from base
group by "month"
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253333/discussion-on-answer-by-rcoupy-how-to-make-a-query-monthly-in-the-context-of-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.